# Heroku Django migration - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy this app to heroku, but i'm getting the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oxm_crm.settings'` when i run **heroku run python manage.py migrate**

**Project structure**

[image: project structure]

---

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
from dj_static import Cling
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'oxm_crm.settings')

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

**manage.py**

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'oxm_crm.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config
from dj_database_url import parse as dburl


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['oxm-crm.herokuapp.com/']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'clientes',
    'contratos',
    'bootstrapform',
    'mathfilters',
    'home',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'oxm_crm.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'oxm_crm.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

default_dburl = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')

DATABASES = { 'default': config('DATABASE_URL', default=default_dburl, cast=dburl), }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'listaCliente'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 16, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 343, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 232, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 226, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oxm_crm.settings'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the colour coding of the file tree, this seems like IntelliJ based IDE and knowing that particular colour, It looks like the settings.py file is in .gitignore